# Long time of importing modules in Python

Tags: python, import, module, anaconda

I have a problem with the time duration of importing modules in my Python script. It takes a few seconds only to import all needed modules, which is a nightmare when developing code.

These are my import times for modules:

- Numpy ~0.25s
- Matplotlib ~1.6s
- Qiskit ~3s
- Pandas ~1s

I use latest version of Anaconda and Python. I have created a virtual environment and there installed all needed modules. Later I use this environment as an interpreter in PyCharm.

If you have any questions about my problem I will try to clarify anything. Thanks in advance!

Comment: These seem quite normal to me, but the timing really depends on what you use to measure it. Imports will be cached from the first time that you run the code, so it should take less if you try to re-import it. It all depends on the hardware that you're running on and which libraries you're importing. Did you try to stack all those imports together? I would not expect the final time to be the sum of all those... In general if you have the right hardware you shouldn't worry to much about this. Just try to avoid imports that you don't need.

Comment: Thank you for response! When I import all the modules at once, it takes about 5 seconds. I am not sure if I have the right hardware, but I have never noticed this problem. What is the most crucial hardware element for compiling code?

Comment: The import depends on many things: CPU, RAM, speed of your disk... If you're trying to run this code on something like raspberry you would notice higher-than-average import speed. However, it really depends from case to case and especially from your development environment. I often develop remotely on servers through SSH connections: when I use notebooks to prototype code, I only import once and then re-use the libraries; when I deploy the code in a script imports usually take less but I never timed them up.

Comment: Okay, thank you! That showed me the problem is quite normal and depends on my hardware.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.